# Sharepoint requires login when opening *.xlsx file but not when opening *.xls file

Tags: sharepoint

If an anonymous user clicks on a link to filename.xlsx, they are prompted for a login ID and password, preventing access to the file.

If the user instead clicks on a link to filename.xls (not xlsx), they are allowed to download the file, no login required.

Why is Sharepoint requiring a login for xlsx files? How do I change it to allow anonymous access to those files?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/anonymous-users-cannot-open-xlsx-files-from-a-document-library

Comment: What happens with a logged in user? Is the XLS still downloaded? Does the XLSX open in the browser by default?

Comment: As a logged in user, when I click on a *.xls file, it offers to open it in Excel. When I click on a *.xlsx file, it downloads it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/anonymous-users-cannot-open-xlsx-files-from-a-document-library) I know enough about the difference between xls and xlsx is, that xlsx is macro enabled.

Comment: XLSX is not necessarily macro-enabled. XLS was used with Excel before version 2007. XLSX was used for Excel 2007 and later. You may be thinking of XLSM, which are XLS files with macros.